# Accessing Docker Container to run command

Tags: docker, ethereum

i'm new to Docker and Ethereum and working through looking to setup an environment to play and access Geth.  I have an ubuntu server in Google Cloud.  I followed instructions on this docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/. Then, i ran the docker command per the instructions:

```
docker run -d --name ethereum-node -v /Users/<user>/ethereum:/root \
           -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 \
           ethereum/client-go
```

Then i ran the command

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                   NAMES
7e5e61551333        ethereum/client-go   "geth"                   10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:8545->8545/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30303->30303/tcp, 8546/tcp, 30303/udp   ethereum-node
```

When i run the command below, i want to access Geth in the Docker container, but doesn't find it.  Is there a way to ensure i'm accessing it in that Docker container?

```
geth

Command 'geth' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install geth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i clearly understand your question,

The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container
check the doc

try this :

```
docker exec -ti ethereum-node sh -c "geth"
```

Comment: I get this error when i run that command:  Error response from daemon: Container 0c5e3c3139b71132c9f2628aa1f8c2b6509b3b7eaf5a048c4818c37a4ac86ec4 is not running

Comment: you have to run the container first : docker run ethereum/client-go

Comment: I just noticed it was shutting down due to this: Low disk space. Gracefully shutting down Geth to prevent database corruption. available=154.73MiB

Comment: i see, you should run the container before you run the command exec